# Find detached items on tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, detach

How could a find the ID of a detached item on a treeview?

I need it to create a filter to a treeview I use like a table in my app.
I have an entry used to input the query and I want to hide the items that doesn't match the query, when user changes the entry content, the table will automatically be re-filtered reattaching items hidden before by detach method.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get the list of detached items from a Treeview. I suppose all your item are on the same level since you use the Treeview as a table, so you could just store all the IDs in a list.

Comment: I couldn't find another way. I had to store every detached item ID.